# Como aplicar um style condicional no angular 8

Tags: angular, ionic

Bom dia

Gostaria de incluir uma formatação condicional no css do meu projeto.

Esse estilo mudaria conforme o status do produto e os status são: Novo serviço, Em andamento, Finalizado ou cancelado.

```
<p class="finalizado">
    {{ appointment.status }}
</p>
```

Essa seria a tag que mudaria a cor conforme a informação do `appointment.status`.

As outras classes serão:

```
.andamento {
   color: #120ecc !important;
}
.solicitado {
   color: #7717c0 !important;
}
.cancelado {
   color: #CC000C !important;
}
```

Comment: Não ficou clara sua pergunta, se o que quer mudar é a classe ou a tag!

Comment: Quero mudar a classe

Comment: Mas qual são as outras classes?

Comment: Incluir as classes na questão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode usar o ng Class

```
<p [ngClass]="{
     'sua-classe': appointment.status==='teste',
     'sua-outra-classe': appointment.status==='banana'
}" >
```

Comment: Muito obrigado já resolveu o meu problema. Mas poderia me ajudar em uma nova dúvida? Teria algum jeito de passar uma propriedade para dentro do arquivo css. Por exemplo, a cor padrão de uma classe é 'red' e passar pelo HTML o 'blue' e chamar essa cor passada pelo HTML e alterar.

Comment: Não tem como iann